# New entity type " Company" in MMA 12

Tags: import, curated-data

New entity type namely Company and Financial have been added to MA 12 to import a company specific financial information. For example:

```
Interpreter["Company"]["FB"]["Dataset"]
```

Produces the following results:
[image]

In the example above, I can easily change the ticker symbol and get similar data for another company. Similarly, I can import company's financial statements data for a specific company [[example taken from here]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/Company.html)

```
Entity["Company", "EBay::k42w2"][ "Dataset"]
```

[image]

I am trying to import similar data (financial statements data shown in the second image) for another public company.  My question is how to download similar data shown in the second image for another company say Facebook or Apple. I might be missing something here. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Since you withhold the retrieval  code you used in your query concerning the "another public company", I don't see how any answer is possible.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I have not hidden any code. All codes used are displayed here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: All the codes displayed work. If all the codes displayed are all the codes you are concerned with, what's the problem?

Comment: @MichaelE2, I reworded my question. I hope that I made it clearer. Thank you.

Comment: If this is what you mean, then it might be clearer to point out the problem: "When I execute `Entity["Company", "FB"]["Dataset"]`, the dataset returned contains all blanks and no financial information at all."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
EntityValue[Interpreter["Company"]["FB"], "Company"]["Dataset"]
```

[image]

Or

```
{CompanyData[EntityValue[Interpreter["Company"]["AAPL"], "Company"], 
  "Dataset"], 
 CompanyData[EntityValue[Interpreter["Company"]["FB"], "Company"], 
  "Dataset"]}
```

[image]